# What are the existing solutions for creating object graphs in an interpreter?

Tags: programming-languages, interpreters, implementations

Please let me know if this isn't the right SE site (or otherwise) for this kind of question, it's the best match I could find.

I'm working on a humble interpreter written in C for a simple language I'm designing. I ran into a design problem in the interpreter which I'm sure people have already solved, and I would like to learn about the existing solutions to this.

Consider there's a builtin `String` type in the language.
And in the interpreter each object has a `attributes` hash table associated with it. It maps a `String*` key to a `Object*` value.

Where do I have problems? Each `String` instance should have methods which operate on it: E.g. `.length()`, `.at_index()` etc.

The way I thought to implement this, is have the C function which is responsible to create `String` objects, also put the methods (`Function` objects) in the new object's `attributes` table, under the matching `String` keys.

This crashes the interpreter (the C program itself) with a Stack Overflow, because it means creating a new `String` has to create a new `String`, and so on...

I can probably work around this issue, maybe by specifically caching `String`s (which is a good idea anyway), but I get the feeling that maybe this design is problematic in the first place.

Is it? How do existing language implementations, mainly simple ones, accomplish this?

Comment: if your attributes hash only contains string keys, consider specializing it so that it doesn't need full String objects. A `char*` will likely do, you can box/unbox as necessary. The Perl interpreter uses this approach. Alternatively, preallocate incomplete objects for the string attributes hash keys and fix up pointers in a second step in order to make the object graph circular. Ensure that the cached strings are used for the hash keys. Many complex object systems feature such circularities that need to be set up manually during startup.

Comment: As @amon noted, most systems with circular dependencies have some "bootstrap" mechanism to build the initial structures. The functions used during the bootstrap are allowed to "cheat", for example instead of looking up functions using String* which isn't fully available yet they use hardcoded function references. This is a very interesting aspect of language implementation, and it's worth studying how existing systems do it.

Comment: Sounds like you're stuck in a meta loop. You want a string. you want a string about that string. But wait now that string needs a string about it.  The simple solution is to segregate info from meta info and don't create meta info about meta info.

Comment: @candied_orange Let me see if I get what you mean. "info" would be an object stored in some `attributes` table, and "meta info" would be the `String` object key which said object is mapped to? If so, do you mean I should just "cheat", and while all objects generally have some metadata about them (such as an attribute `String` which specifies the class name), objects which serve as the metadata mechanism will not have that metadata (such as the `String` keys in the `attributes` table themselves)? Even though they're of the same type in the type system?

Comment: @AvivCohn if you want a more general application of this idea think of it like this. You must be acyclical. If x can beget y and y can beget z then don't let y or z beget x or you'll never get off this crazy ride. That doesn't mean you only can have two kinds of information. It means you need to know which of the many kinds you have and don't let them loop you back where you've been.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your interpreter sits outside the language. It doesn't have to abide by the rules of the language. If it cannot initialize a property of an object because that property requires something else that doesn't exist yet, just don't initialize it, and wait until whatever you need to initialize it exists.